# How to plot an interpolating function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab task to do , I want to put n distinct interpolation points in different locations in the interval [−1, 1] and plot ωn(x).

ωn(x) = |(x − x0)(x − x1)· · ·(x − xn)|

here is my code :

```
x=linspace(-1,1,5);
k=1.5;
wx=1;
for i=1:length(x)
    w=abs(k-x(i))*wx;
    wx=w;
end
plot(x,w,'c*')
```

Am I doing correct?

thanks

Comment: Mathematically I would say no. You're calculating the product of the absolute values but should take the absolute value of the products instead.

Comment: @MatthiasW. I think absolute value has [multiplicativeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) property

Comment: @A_C: you may be right. Might have been too early. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the way you are trying to plot your data, you plot the last value of w against all x entries. I added two new lines to plot `w` value calculated on specific `x` value:

```
x=linspace(-1,1,5);
W  = [] ;
k=1.5;
wx=1;
for i=1:length(x)
    w=abs(k-x(i))*wx;
    wx=w
    W(end+1) = w ;
end
plot(x,W,'c*')
```